# Like clause and sql injection

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having a doubt about this situation.

I've a query like this within a Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 like '%' + @column1 + '%'
```

My question is, this is vulnerable to SQL Injection? Do I need to change this to something like this: (?)

```
declare @column1Like nvarchar(200);

@column1Like = '%' + @column1 + '%'

SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 like @column1Like
```

Regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quick answer is no. To be vulnerable to SQL injection one must be using dynamic SQL execution.

**This** would be vulnerable:

```
EXECUTE ('SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE column1 like ' + @column1Like);
```

That also means there is no real difference between both of your examples (from a security standpoint at least).

Comment: Isn't it vulnerable for a "second level injection". I mean it won't be a pure SQL injection, but the result may contain quite a lot of things it shouldn't if the user uses special characters in `@column1`. For example, what happens if the value of `@column1` is empty or a single `%`? That gets all the rows in the table.

Comment: @tiz yes of course, you would have to treat that separately (e.g. by limiting the minimum length of @column1Like). The type of injection we're talking here is something like `@column1Like = '''''; DROP TABLE table1'` though - that is what is avoided by using SQL parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Like is no different from `=` or any other predicate.

However the user can inject additionnal wildcard characters (`%`, `_`) in the pattern; if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 like '%' + @column1 + '%'
```

Since this query only works with variables, it has no place to put code instead of data and hence is not vulnerable to `SQL` injection.

I am of course assuming that `@column1` here is an `SQL Server` variable and you are using parametrized query functionality in your client-side language to bind a value to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm very careful about security issues. But this one I didn't catch :P

Answer (score 2):

I think it is vulnerable, for example : 
**'%' or 1=1--** 
will show all registers of the database if you don´t format it like `@column1Like`.

In this case, I think it´s the same than (`@column1Like= ''` or `@column1Like is null`)
but you must think another examples like

```
'%' union select SELECT `column11`, `column22`
FROM table2 where `colum11` -- is the same type than `column1` 
--and `column22` is the same type than `column22`.
```

Comment: Pretty late comment, but this is definitely *not* true.

Answer (score 1):

It is not vulnerable since it already is a string value in the SQL space. Although, it could break the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not vulnerable to SQL injection in either case because you are using a parameterized query.