# Is this code in a stored procedure sql-injectible

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

If I have a where clause in a stored procedure that concatenates a search string that comes from the front end (user supplied) ... like this:

```
FirstName like '%'+@SearchString+'%'
```

Can this be injected with malicious code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Like clause and sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805264/like-clause-and-sql-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

As long as you are using it as shown the worst any one can do is enter characters of significance in the `like` syntax such as `%` or `[0-9]`.

It would be a SQL injection risk if you concatenated it into a string that you then executed but it just gets treated as data below

```
Select *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE FirstName like '%'+@SearchString+'%'
```